# Select data from two tables. one table is parent/child and I need to get the parents without a relation

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database

I have two tables

products

```
id  |  catID  |  UID
--------------------
1   |  3      |  3
```

categories

```
id  |  cat_name  |  parent
--------------------------
2   |  XYZ       |  0
3   |  abc       |  2
```

I need to pull each product and its related category AND that categories related parent based solely on the id of the product....

I have tried a couple of variations but can not quite get the parent categories into the fetch. There is no relationship for parent categories in the products table.

```
SELECT
  a.product_name, a.catID, b.cat_name, b.parent
FROM
  products a, categories b
WHERE
  a.id = '$_SESSION[spid]' 
  AND b.id = a.catID
  OR b.id = b.parent /// not correct..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select p.*,c1.cat_name as category, c2.cat_name as parent_category
from products p
left join categories c1 on (c1.id=p.catId)
left join categories c2 on (c1.parent=c2.id)
```

Comment: what exactly is "on" doing?

Comment: The `on` bit tells the server what columns you're suppose to join on.  C1 is being joined on the category id in the products and the categories table.  This means it's the item's category.

Comment: One more question.. what if the parent category has a parent. can i still grab this as well. I tried the different join methods on this script and could not get it to fetch anything beyond the first parent category.

Comment: Sure.  Just add the line left join categories c3 on (c2.parent=c3.id). And add c3.cat_name to the select.